# Can I do mysql replication with server dynamic ip address

Tags: mysql

I have mysql server master having dynamic ip address as my internet service provider can not give me the static one.

Is there any other option to replicate mysql data with ip address change all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to host/ replicate mysql server with dynamic ip by using LogMein Hamachi. By install to both of Mysql server (windows), create and join the network, I can comunicate between the master and slave without worrying the public ip change.

Answer (score 0):

well you have to try to use the "%" for the host part :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Make sure that the changes talk affect with:

```
flush privileges
```

else, you shall better use OpenVPN or an SSH Tunneling to avoid these problems.

Comment: I have dynamic ip on master server

Comment: I decide to add my solution for someone really want to achieve what I faced. I use hamachi vpn free creating private network. from there I can use hamachi ip for Mysql server without worrying change of my public ip address get from ISP.[https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/hamachi/vpn/whatsnew.aspx]