# Replicate locally hosted MySQL database to server

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication

I want a local MySQL database to be replicated in a server database which is hosted in the server. I cannot use general master slave replication as the master(local computer) doesn't have a static IP. Is there a methodology that I can use, by uploading MySQL transaction log file time to time to server(Eg. once a 5 min.), execute it on server to replicate the locally hosted database. So, what basically done is,

1. Get part of the log updated since the last log position synched to slave(server) from master(local computer)
2. Server(slave) executes the retrieved log time to time(Eg. cron job)(logs can be sequentially numbered to avoid any database issue.)

Though getting a whole local backup, uploading it to server and executtion is a possibility, that is not feasible as size of local database gets larger rapidly.

Comment: You can set up a VPN between the two, and not have to worry about dynIP changes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873212/can-i-do-mysql-replication-with-server-dynamic-ip-address

Comment: @Hexchaimen Thank you for your suggestion. VPN is not a valid option in this scenario. That's why we're looking for an alternative.